# BigTable Emulator cbt gives error on creating table "transport: authentication handshake failed: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I am using "cbt" Cloud BigTable CLI Tool.
After setting the variables in .cbtrc file: Image attached
[image]

BigTable emulator is running:
**btemulator.exe --host=localhost --port=8086
[bigtable] Cloud Bigtable emulator running on 127.0.0.1:8086**

When i run the command:
**cbt createtable my-table**

I am getting error:
Creating table: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"

Comment: Hello,from this error doc [1], it seems like the issue is transient. Could you please check if you still have the error?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/status-codes

Answer (score 2):

.rc files are a standard for UNIX systems, but not so much for Windows.

In this case, we can check the code of the `cbt` command to check how does it find the .cbtrc file, and it's [in this piece of code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/3a12a18dfdff1de27456ac160408302ab4c8d93f/bigtable/internal/cbtconfig/cbtconfig.go#L115):

```go
// Filename returns the filename consulted for standard configuration.
func Filename() string {
    // TODO(dsymonds): Might need tweaking for Windows.
    return filepath.Join(os.Getenv("HOME"), ".cbtrc")
}
```

The code gets the `HOME` env variable, but this is not available in windows (some details in [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/q/607105)). The [windows equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory#Default_home_directory_per_operating_system) is `%HOMEPATH%`. There is even a TODO on the code to make it work better in windows.

This means that the cbt command is not finding the config file, so it's not applying it.

You can set the `HOME` env variable in your machine, or you can pass the command flags on the command directly:

```
cbt -project fake-project -instance fake-instance -admin-endpoint localhost:8086 -data-endpoint localhost:8086 -creds C:\path\to\your\creds -auth-token <TOKEN> createtable my-table
```

Additionally, you have to set the right environment variables for `cbt` to understand it is running on an emulator. This means setting the `BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable.

On a linux machine, without setting the right env, I get the same error, but it works after setting the right env:

```
$ cbt -project test -instance test -admin-endpoint localhost:8086 -data-endpoint localhost:8086 createtable test
2020/10/13 08:23:13 Creating table: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake"

$ $(gcloud beta emulators bigtable env-init)

$ cbt -project test -instance test -admin-endpoint localhost:8086 -data-endpoint localhost:8086 createtable test

$ cbt -project test -instance test -admin-endpoint localhost:8086 -data-endpoint localhost:8086 ls
test
```

In the `cbt` code we can also see that, if that environment variable is set, it makes the call insecure, but if it's not set, it tries to make the call secure, hence the TLS error (the local emulator does not set up secure endopoints).

This can be seen in [this piece of code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/2d6831000572ad5d3fd04a996d0562faea24075a/bigtable/internal/option/option.go#L83):

```go
// DefaultClientOptions returns the default client options to use for the
// client's gRPC connection.
func DefaultClientOptions(endpoint, scope, userAgent string) ([]option.ClientOption, error) {
    var o []option.ClientOption
    // Check the environment variables for the bigtable emulator.
    // Dial it directly and don't pass any credentials.
    if addr := os.Getenv("BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST"); addr != "" {
        conn, err := grpc.Dial(addr, grpc.WithInsecure())
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("emulator grpc.Dial: %v", err)
        }
        o = []option.ClientOption{option.WithGRPCConn(conn)}
    } else {
        o = []option.ClientOption{
            option.WithEndpoint(endpoint),
            option.WithScopes(scope),
            option.WithUserAgent(userAgent),
        }
    }
    return o, nil
}
```

---

**In summary**: make sure you're setting the right environment variables for `cbt` to work. For the specific error you're seeing, it's probably the `BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST` variable missing.